# Display Image only for specific input Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

The resulting program should load a image when the input fields are filled in as follows:

**File size field** – 300x250 or 728x90
**File extension field** – gif

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-init="baseUrl='https://static.abc.com/images/test/'">

File name: input style="width:225px" ng-model="filename" value="{{filename}}"><br>

File extension: input style="width:30px" ng-model="extension" value="{{extension}}"><br><br>

<!-- Add code below this line -->


</div>

</body>
```

Not able to think of the code further to achieve the result.

Comment: Need to put more effort into finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Angular offers two scope methods `$watchGroup` (since 1.3) and `$watchCollection`.

However more generalised solution is to watch the two ng-model and check if the values match with your required values then show the image.

```
$scope.$watch('[filename,extension]', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    var new_filename  = newValue[0];
    var new_extension = newValue[1];
    if(new_filename == '<what ever>' && new_extension == '<what ever>'){
         $scope.isShowImg = true;
    }
    else
         $scope.isShowImg = false;
}, true);
```

On the image tag in view apply the `isShowImg`.

```
<img src = "" ng-show="isShowImg" />
```

And on controller load declare isShowImg as false so that image does not display at loading.

```
$scope.isShowImg = false
```

Example of using `watchCollection`

```
$scope.$watchCollection(['filename', 'extension'], function(newValues, oldValues){
    // do what you want here
});
```

Example of using `watchGroup`

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['filename', 'extension'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
  //do what you want here
});
```